# C# Combining conditions

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
if (thedata[m].ToUpper() == thedata[m] && thedata[m].Contains(" ") || (thedata[m - 1] == "" && thedata[m].Contains(Speaking)))
```

Instead of rewriting everything up to `Contains()`, is there a way to combine it into one `Contains()`?

Would this be done using an `string[]` where each string of characters I want to put into the `Contains()` is its own string?

Can these be combined, if so, how?

Comment: what kind of question is this ??? please be more specific.

Comment: It seems any sort of combining is already done. Please specify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not out of the box. String.Contains has no overload for that purpose.

What you could do is write an extension method yourself so that you could use it several times.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
      public static bool Contains(this string input, params string[] queries)
      {
           foreach (string s in queries)
           {
                if (!input.Contains(s)) return false;
           }

           return true;
      }
}
```

After which you could simply call

```
if (thedata[m].Contains(" ", "Speaking")) && {rest of your expression})
```